# Duplicated value in ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I'm using last version of Angular and my current golas is to create an array of string representing the structure of a json object, like

> ['id', 'address:street', 'address:zipcode',..]

the following snippet is what ive achieved till now

```
   <div *ngFor="let prop of propKeys(fetchedData)">
      <div *ngIf="checkIfObject(fetchedData[prop])">
         <span *ngFor="let subProp of propKeys(fetchedData[prop])" style="padding-left: 15px;">{{addToResult(prop + ':' +subProp)}}</span>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="!checkIfObject(fetchedData[prop])">
         <span>{{addToResult(prop)}}</span>
     </div>
   </div>
```

and this is the .ts file

```
export class ProjectNewComponent implements OnInit {
    fetchedData: any;
    nestedResult: any[] = [];
    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
        this._http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
               if(Array.isArray(data))
                   this.fetchedData = data[0];
               else
                   this.fetchedData = data;
               console.log(Object.keys(this.fetchedData));
            })
    }

    ngOnInit() {}

    propKeys(obj: any){
        return Object.keys(obj);
    }

    checkIfObject(item: any){
      return item instanceof Object;
    }

    addToResult(val: any){
      this.nestedResult.push(val);
      return val;
    }

    printResult(){
      console.log(this.nestedResult);
      this.nestedResult = [];
    }
}
```

all works well except that when i click the button to print the result i see duplicated result

> ['id', 'address:street', 'address:zipcode','id', 'address:street']

even if the html output is correct

My workaround is to update the function that populate that list

```
addToResult(val: any){
    if(this.nestedResult.filter(item => item === val).length === 0)
        this.nestedResult.push(val);
    return val;
}
```

but i can't understand why the array have duplicated values.
Is there some error in code ?

Comment: this.nestedResult.filter(item => item === val).length === 0 is the right condition added for the workaround

Comment: I didn't quite get your issue here.

Comment: A template interpolation **should not have side effects**. You are invoking `addToResult` in your template, and this changes the array structure